# Word to describe someone who likes physical contact/touching in a non-sexual way

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm struggling how to describe someone who likes non-sexual physical contact, such as touching, hugging and/or does these kind of actions regularly.

As a German, my first thought was "touchy", however that seems to mean something different. "Handsy" seems to have negative implications and imply some kind of molestation-component, as in forcing themselves on others. I'm looking for a word that just describes someone who is very comfortable with and really enjoys regular physical contact. Is there such a word?

It would be used like "John is a very [x] person, he always hugs people on their first meeting"

Comment: ***Tactile*** is a bit of a 50-cent word. Conversationally, many linguistically impoverished speakers might say John is a [***touchy-feely***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touchy-feely) kind of guy. But this is often used metaphorically of someone who likes talking about *emotional* feelings, rather than someone who likes physical contact with others.

Comment: "cuddly" might work.

Comment: Skinship  a Japanese and Korean derived word describes the type of intimacy in your question. Not sure how to characterize a person who craves skinship in a single word.

Comment: Gregarious gets close to describing such a person.

Comment: loosely related: [How to say “I love children” without being misunderstood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344440/how-to-say-i-love-children-without-being-misunderstood)

Comment: kissing, hugging, embracing and holding hands are all manifestations of affection. You can describe yourself as being *affectionate*, and in touch with your feelings, although that doesn't necessarily imply you are [**openly affectionate**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/affectionate). Hey, got it just as I was writing.

Answer (score 12):

***Tactile***

> (of a person) given to touching other people, especially as an unselfconscious expression of sympathy or affection.

([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tactile))

Comment: Please always mention the source by name, and if it's online, add a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most common use, but **[haptic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haptic)** also fits.

From MW:

> 2. characterized by a predilection for the sense of touch
>
> a *haptic* person

Comment: Heh. Definitely an odd response, but I could see somebody like Neil Stephenson  word in this way. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You can also say two words, physically affectionate or just affectionate or cuddly.